# Vue-chartjs with axios for stacked bar chart

Tags: vue.js, axios, chart.js, stacked-chart, vue-chartjs

In my template, I have

```html
<BarChart
  v-if="loaded"
  :data1="data1"
  :data2="data2"
  :chart-labels="labels"
/>
```

for the script part, I have

```js
this.loaded = false
axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
  this.data1 = response.data.xxx
  this.loaded = true
  axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
    this.data2 = response.data.xxx
    this.loaded = true
  })
})
```

for the barchart vue, I have

```js
export default {
  extends: Bar,
  props: {
      data1: {
        type: [Array, Object],
        required: false
      },
      data2: {
        type: [Array, Object],
        required: false
      },
      chartLabels: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
      }
    },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(
      {
        labels: this.chartLabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "data1",
            backgroundColor: "#f87979",
            data: this.data1
          },
           {
            label: "data2",
            backgroundColor: "#6bb6ef",
            data: this.data2
          },
        ],
      },
........
```

In other words,
I called first axios for data1 and then second axios for data2. Both set this.loaded=true;
However, the chart only shows the first data instead of both data1 and data2. I think it's because of the this.loaded.

How to correctly implement this when calling two axios api to render stacked bar chart?

Comment: Are you sure that you can have `data1` and `data2` as props ? Did you tried with static arrays before trying it with the API response ? By that I mean: try to fetch the API, write down the arrays into `data` and see if it works with it like this at first.

Comment: yes they both can get data1 and 2, but can only show one. (depends on where I put this.loaded = true)

Comment: Do you want to rewrite it but with `async`/`await` ? Will be easier to understand things thanks to it IMO.

Comment: thanks for advice. will it produce different result?

Comment: It will help you with your current callbackHell: http://callbackhell.com/ Hence, the code will be less error prone and more readable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right about `this.loaded = true`. Try setting it once AFTER the second API call for data2.

However, the main problem appears to be a typo in your axios calls.  You are setting data1 twice:

```
this.loaded = false
axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
  this.data1 = response.data.xxx
  this.loaded = true
  axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
    this.data1 = response.data.xxx
    this.loaded = true
  })
})
```

change the second axios get call to data2:

```
this.loaded = false
axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
  this.data1 = response.data.xxx
  //this.loaded = true
  axios.get(`url`).then((response) => {
    this.data2 = response.data.xxx
    this.loaded = true
  })
})
```

Also, make sure that your URLs are different and correct in your actual code.

Comment: yes I've already tried the second part of your code, it will only show data2 if you don't call this.loaded = true in data1's axios.